# 404 page in React renders in every page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a Route file which contains multiple routes like this

```
const RouteUI = ({context}) =>
  <Switch>
  <React.Fragment>

    <SDPRouteUI context={context} />

    <SDPMRouteUI context={context} />

    <ACRouteUI context={context} />

    <DCRouteUI context={context} />

    <Route path=""
      render={() =>
        <NotFound context={context} />
      }
    />

  </React.Fragment>

  </Switch>
```

The NotFound component is getting rendered on every page,even though it is inside switch.

SDPRouteUI,SDPMRouteUI..etc are other route files like

```
const SDPRouteUI = ({context}) =>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/sdp/account'
      render={() =>
        <SDPAccountPageSF context={context} />
      }
    />

    <Route exact path='/sdp/activate/back'
      render={() =>
        <SDPActivateBackSF context={context} />
      }
    />
<Switch>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Top level Switch statement doesn't work because the first element being not a Route is automatically rendered which in your case is `React.Fragment`. Even if you move Switch element to between `React.Fragment` it wouldn't work as the other default component would render.

In order to handle nested routes you need to have a Provider/Consumer pattern. Refer **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929472/react-router-v4-default-pagenot-found-page/52261444#52261444)** to handle 404 Routes correctly

Comment: @ShubhamChopra PLease let me know if the above answer helped you or not

Comment: Not exactly but was useful.Thanks

Comment: Your answer combined with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155909/how-to-use-context-api-with-react-router-v4) saved my ass. Your answer helped me to get a better idea.
My problem was in that <Switch /> only works right with <Route /> components as its immediate children.

Comment: Agree with @MickeyDickey - this is key `...<Switch /> only works right with <Route /> components as its immediate children`

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to achieve 404 in react router. Inside react router component, create a route without path defined. And make sure to place the code at the bottom of all routes, so that router will check all the routes and fallback if no match found.

```
<Router>
   <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
   <Link to="/search?q=react">Search</Link>
   <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
   <Route exact path="/search" component={SearchPage} />
   <Route component={NoMatchPage} />
</Router>
```

Visit any random URL, you will see a simple 404 page. But wait, let's check whether other pages work normally without breaking. It won't!
Check on about link, you will see both about and 404 page get rendered. Because first router matched the exact route for /about path and then it traverses to the bottom and load the 404 route since this route have no path defined.
React router provide a component called Switch to break once a route get resolved and not load any other route component below it.
Its fairly easy to implement. Enclose all the route inside Switch component. lets do it and make the 404 page works without error.

```
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <section className="App">
      <Router>
        ...
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={IndexPage} />
          ...
          <Route exact path="/search" component={SearchPage} />
          <Route component={NoMatchPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </section>
  );
};

...
```

This Switch component will check for the matching route, if a route is already matched, it breaks checking the next routes. By this way, we will avoid rendering 404 route for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

`<Route component={NotFound} />` , maybe fix your problem

If u define any route without "path" prop, the switch component will automatically move to the NotFound component.

`<Route exact strict component ={NotFound} />`, can be more useful. For exact Route.