# using context with an api call for the root level component and using the context across the child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to implement the context , so when my sample app loads i will hit an api and get the data then i am trying to set that value to context and save there

once it is saved only i will load the Router which is my root level component.

So then i am trying to access the context values in the children component like profile.

tried creating the context file but don't how to use properly for this case.

Any help appreciated.

```js
class App extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        this._fetchData()
    }

    _fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://www.example.com", {method: "GET"})
        const data = await response.json()
        // how can i use context and set the value
    }

    // how should i use a provider to the router so basically i need to get the data every where in the route
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
            { Object.keys(context.data).length > 0 ?
                <Layout>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/sample" exact component={SampleHomePage} />
                        <Route path="/sample/profile" component={SampleProfile} />
                        <Route path="/sample/about" component={SampleAbout}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Layout>
                : <p>Data Loading </p>}
            </Router>
        )
    }
}


// profile.js

import React from  'react';

const profile = () => {
  //how to get the contex value here
}

export default profile


// dataContext.js

import React from 'react';

const DataContext = React.creatContext({
  data: {}
})

export default DataContext
```

Comment: in fetchData set data from api into state, after that in render method pass data from state into context.provider component

Comment: may be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50158702/4061006 !

Comment: tried that one didn't get