How to create a global wrapper with some conf, and get the conf in a specific component
I will try to explain what I want to do with a simple example.
I have a component that creates a css grid layout, that adapt to the screen. In this component, I have a function that checks the screen size using useMediaQuery. The limits are set in the component with a default value (992px for example).
But if someone wants to use it and set the limit to another value than 992px, I can of course add it as a prop, but that means that every time we use the component, we have to set the prop. boring.
I have other props that I want to set globally, and I dont want to use same props every time I use it.
So my question is, can I make a wrapper, that we should put in the app.tsx (or wherever), add configuration to this wrapper, and get the configuration inside the component ?
I don't know exactly how to do that

You are touching on design system concepts. Design system implementations typically have a configurable theme  that is at the root of your app. It may be worth you looking at examples of such impls or adopting them. Tailwind, PandaCSS, Chakra etc

However if you want an ad hoc solution you could have the media query inside useMediaQuery reference a CSS variable for the number instead of via a prop. You can then set that CSS variable high up in your app. You could still allow prop override too if you wanted. This is basically what many design systems do under the hood.

@adsy thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I think I have more than CSS, it would work but not as I wanted to. I finally managed it by creating a provider using react context. Now on top level, i can put a , and in every component, it takes the value from the context. this post helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61660837/23396078
